# MSAL + Graph AcquireTokenForClient Issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Intermittent Issue or stops working  after a while: SSL error while calling  AcquireTokenForClient from .NET Core WEB API.

Works fine in Dev machine. Seeing this issue in server and not sure when it stops. IIS server is running on-prem and calling Azure AD with MSAL.

Code directly used from Microsoft Sample to connect to Graph....

```
 app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(AuthHelper.ClientId)
       .WithTenantId(AuthHelper.Tenant)
       .WithClientSecret(AuthHelper.ClientSecret)
       .Build();

        // a tenant administrator
       `string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

Exception: 
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.\nTrace
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: It's saying that SSL connection not established. Have you installed ssl certificate in IIS? I think MS graph is expecting traffic over HTTPS only. Please verify in iis first.